# com.android.phone force closes constantly after a clean install of CM7.1 in SGS1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, cyanogenmod, force-close

I installed a CM7.1 over a custom 2.3.5 installation on my Samsung Galaxy S I9000.  I did a full wipe through CWM as well as wiping the cache, as explained in the [SGS installation instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S%3a_Full_Update_Guide#Method_via_Recovery).  The installation completed without any errors, but when the phone booted the process *com.android.phone* force-closed.  When I dismissed the error, it force-closed again within less than a second, and continued doing so.

I rebooted into recovery and made sure to wipe everything, but nothing helped.  I finally reverted to my previous ROM in disappointment.

What could be the causing these force-closes?  How can I install CM7.1 successfully?  Is there any specific kernel I should install?  Any specific modem?

Comment: FCs are often caused by an Java exception. Those exceptions get loged in the system log. It sure would be helpfull if you could show us that [system log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log).

Comment: I had more serious problems the first time I flashed CM7.1, and flashing it again after I had cleared the data worked.  (Make sure you wipe data and not just cache.)  That said, I had other problems with CM later and went back to my old ROM.

Comment: @Matthew: What serious problems did you have?  Was this with the stable version?

Comment: Partition issues and resets.  Then a few days after the successful install most of my apps started crashing :P and yes, it was the "stable" release.

Comment: @NathanFellman did you solve your problem? If so, could you add your solution as an answer (and accept it), so it may help others encountering the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching this in local forums, it turned out to a SIM card issue.  My carrier had a series of yellow SIM cards that for some reason caused this problem.  I had my carrier replace it, and I've been on CM ever since (with a short break for AOKP).