# All non stock apps are crashing

Tags: applications, crashes, insufficient-memory

Suddely without any previous event my application has started crashing. Only stock applications work? Cleared cache of some of them but nothing happened. Do you have any ideas, or I will have to make a factory reset?:S

EDIT!!!!

I have a great hint...I trie to reinstall an app and I got an error telling that there is insufficient space in my phone. Any ideas?:)

Comment: Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Yeap, many times...

Comment: Sounds like you'd need a factory reset then :(

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache (or data) for the Launcher?

Comment: Also: What device? OS? Rooted?

Comment: You should take a [look at the system log.](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log) Maybe there is a hint in it about this strange behavior.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy, Froyo. Not rooted.
How do I clean the Launcher's cach? There is no such application :S

I cannot view system log, because I cannot run any applications:(

Comment: @peraueb8921 You can view the system log without an Android App via the `adb` utility.

Answer (score 1):

I have this happen from time to time. My issue is usually just about any application, not just "non-stock".

To fix it I have to reboot in to the recovery and clear the cache. I believe that it has to do with the number of applications that I have installed, ~105 total, and the amount of data they store in the cache.

Clearing the cache usually fixes it, but only for a short time, unless I remove some applications. I am now down to about 80 and I haven't had the issue in a couple weeks.

Comment: How can I reboot in recovery and clean the cache? I removed may apps and it seems a little better...

Comment: I can't answer that if you have an unrooted phone, I rooted my device as I was walking out of the t-mobile store. It also depends on the device you have, and I don't even remember if the stock recovery has the option to clear the cache, I think it does, but it's been a while since I've seen it.

Comment: So I cant avoid factory reset if I am not root?

Comment: No, you can factory reset. but I dont know how to tell you to get in to recovery. My Galaxy S, for example, I hold down the volume down + power while the device is off, then when the "vibrant screen" pops up, I release the power, and continue to hold the volume down and I get in to recovery. But I don't know if the option to clear the cache is in the stock recovery, factory reset is.

Comment: I have made an edit, please check it out :)

I have Galaxy S, too. I will give it a try

Comment: I booted in recovery mode, cleared the cache partition but the problems are still there.