# My messaging application sometimes closes itself while typing - How can I fix this?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-2

When typing an SMS message, the messaging application will automatically close and the typed text is deleted, causing me to have to retype the text. It seems to happen after two or three messages. I have clear data of Messaging software from `Manage Applications->All->Messaging->Clear Data` but the problem persists. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: [The Android log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log) will most likely show the cause for the close, which should help you to find a solution.

Comment: Does it force close, or just close onto the home screen?

Comment: it close on to the home screen.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to investigate this issue more deeply based on system logs. Install some application to grabbing logs from device (for example SendLog). When you application crashes, then grab system log in which should be placed callstack started in your application.

Getting logs should be done asap after crash, because these files rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I would try going in to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All` and select the Messaging app. Then the Clear Data for the application. There may be something in the data that is corrupt and causing an issue.

I know this doesn't necessarily solve the problem, but you can try using another SMS application, like [Handcent SMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en) for example. I personally never liked the Messaging application that comes in TouchWiz (Samsung's additions/changes to Android), which is why I moved to a custom ROM as soon as a stable one was made available. That is not the answer for everyone, but replacing the messaging app with a 3rd party app is "the next best thing".

Comment: Don't forget to clear cache, too.

Comment: Dear Ryan i have done your solution. but after a week same problem occurred but now time span of its occurrence is reduced. what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible, but unlikely, that it is being killed by the android automatic killer to free up ram, but as the Samsung Galaxy S2 has 1 GB of ram this is unlikely.

One other explanation is that you are accidentally pressing the home button while you type, or are pressing something on your keyboard that has the same effect.

If possible, install the drivers for your device, download adb + required dll's, and type into a command prompt:

```
logcat >> logcat.log
```

Then make it happen. This will dump all of the logs to the logcat.log file. You could then paste this into pastebin, for us to have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the damn app alone, it's black and uninviting anyway, and install a more appealing SMS app, try Go SMS or Handcent SMS.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try looking at what processes are running, you probably have a game or application with some services maybe even something with an SMS intent grabber to read when you have messages & alert you or whatever.

[Avast](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) is good for monitoring applications resources & uninstalling them if you don't like doing it in the settings. It also puts up applications by permissions which make it easy to see if something is grabbing SMS messages off the intent. It's free, you don't need to root, and as long as you don't do the admin mode easy enough to uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

This is old question however answering now since I found solution on my device. It might help for anyone still facing the issue.
There is Android system app "Aries" you need to give all permission to this app.
After that none of the application are now minimizing for me.

My device is running on Andorid 7.