# App installs result in "Process System Not Responding" message

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, installation, force-close

After installing or updating an app in the newest version of the android market I receive the warning "Process System is not responding" with the option to either force close or wait. I choose "wait" and everything continues as normal. It's not a major issue just a mild annoyance, also it interferes with automatic updates.

I have tried fixing permissions, wiping dalvik cache, etc. but to no avail.

Has anyone else seen this issue? I have googled this problem but haven't found too many relevant threads.

I am running CM 7.1.0 android version 2.3.7 with Tiamat kernel 4.1.0.

Here is where I believe the timeout occured:

```
02-06 11:49:02.300 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:03.301 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:04.302 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:05.293 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:07.955 W/ActivityManager( 171): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{40b706d8 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED} - receiver=android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThr ead@40717ca0, started 10002ms ago
02-06 11:49:07.955 W/ActivityManager( 171): Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{40afb560 com.android.server.AppsLaunchFailureReceiver p=0 o=0 m=0x208000}
02-06 11:49:08.235 I/ActivityManager( 171): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=2067 uid=10048 gids={}
```

Here is a longer log:

```
02-06 11:48:57.235 D/installd( 123): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.vevo-1.apk' (success) ---
02-06 11:48:57.245 D/PackageManager( 171): Registered content provider: com.vevo.SearchSuggestionsProvider, className = com.vevo.SearchSuggestionsProvider, isSyncable = false
02-06 11:48:57.245 D/PackageManager( 171): Providers: com.vevo.SearchSuggestionsProvider
02-06 11:48:57.245 D/PackageManager( 171): Services: com.vevo.services.VevoService
02-06 11:48:57.245 D/PackageManager( 171): Activities: com.vevo.Startup com.vevo.Home com.vevo.activities.VideosActivity com.vevo.MusicMapActivity com.vevo.QRCodeResultActivity com.vevo.ShareResult com.vevo.activities.RegistrationActivity com.vevo.PreferencesActivity com.vevo.activities.AboutActivity com.vevo.activities.ArtistsActivity com.vevo.activities.ViewArtistActivity com.vevo.PlaylistsActivity com.vevo.activities.MyPlaylistsActivity com.vevo.activities.ViewPlaylistActivity com.vevo.activities.WatchCompletionActivity com.vevo.activities.VevoWatchActivity com.vevo.FlashWatchActivity com.vevo.BrowserActivity com.vevo.activities.SearchResults
02-06 11:48:57.245 I/ActivityManager( 171): Force stopping package com.vevo uid=10144
02-06 11:48:57.435 I/installd( 123): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.vevo-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.vevo-1.apk@classes.dex
02-06 11:48:57.445 D/PackageManager( 171): New package installed in /data/app/com.vevo-1.apk
02-06 11:48:57.965 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:57.975 D/HomeLoaders( 273): application intent received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, replacing=false
02-06 11:48:57.975 D/HomeLoaders( 273): --> package:com.vevo
02-06 11:48:57.975 D/HomeLoaders( 273): --> add package
02-06 11:48:58.106 D/dalvikvm( 171): JIT code cache reset in 3 ms (1048556 bytes 1/0)
02-06 11:48:58.116 D/dalvikvm( 171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1458K, 34% free 8594K/12935K, external 1828K/2161K, paused 98ms
02-06 11:48:58.126 D/Finsky ( 1999): [9] 1.packageInstalled: Package install status for "com.vevo" is 1
02-06 11:48:58.276 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.247 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.657 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.657 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.687 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.707 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.757 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.777 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.817 D/szipinf ( 171): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.917 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:48:59.927 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:49:00.067 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:49:00.088 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:49:00.148 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:49:00.248 D/szipinf ( 317): Initializing inflate state
02-06 11:49:02.300 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:03.301 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:04.302 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:05.293 W/SharedBufferStack( 250): waitForCondition(LockCondition) timed out (identity=3, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
02-06 11:49:07.955 W/ActivityManager( 171): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{40b706d8 android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED} - receiver=android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThr ead@40717ca0, started 10002ms ago
02-06 11:49:07.955 W/ActivityManager( 171): Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{40afb560 com.android.server.AppsLaunchFailureReceiver p=0 o=0 m=0x208000}
02-06 11:49:08.235 I/ActivityManager( 171): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=2067 uid=10048 gids={}
02-06 11:49:08.265 I/Process ( 171): Sending signal. PID: 171 SIG: 3
02-06 11:49:08.265 I/dalvikvm( 171): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
02-06 11:49:08.286 I/ActivityThread( 2067): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider
02-06 11:49:08.366 I/ActivityManager( 171): No longer want com.google.android.maps.mytracks (pid 1520): hidden #16
02-06 11:49:08.386 D/GTalkService( 292): handlePackageInstalled: re-initialize providers
02-06 11:49:08.386 D/GTalkService( 292): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] ##### searchProvidersFromIntent
02-06 11:49:08.386 D/GTalkService( 292): [RawStanzaProvidersMgr] no intent receivers found
02-06 11:49:08.396 I/dalvikvm( 171): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-06 11:49:08.396 I/Process ( 171): Sending signal. PID: 265 SIG: 3
02-06 11:49:08.396 I/dalvikvm( 265): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
02-06 11:49:08.396 I/ActivityManager( 171): Start proc com.google.android.partnersetup for broadcast com.google.android.partnersetup/.AppInstalledReceiver: pid=2075 uid=10015 gids={}
```

Comment: If you can consistently reproduce this problem, I suggest retrieving the system log and cut/pasting the areas around the time you get an "Application Not Responding" error here to help us troubleshoot this for you.  You will need Android SDK with USB drivers installed on your PC, or a stand-alone app like aLogCat from the Market: https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

Comment: Yes I can consistently reproduce it. I added the logs above. Thanks! :)

Comment: You mention clearing all the big caches, but have you also tried clearing the Market/Play app's cache? I recently had a similar problem, cleared the app cache and then everything came back to normal.

Comment: @Vapen Did the last hint solve your problem? Would be nice to know if this question found a solution (it's currently still tagged as "unsolved").

Comment: As there's no response to all the hints from the OP (or other people having the problem), I'd recommend to close this question as "too localized".