# Where is the Android log file to see if app installed correctly?

Tags: installation, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log)

Where is the log file. Why not logs/system.log? I see a log using app but nothing about install information.  Like failures to install because of xyz.

Answer (score 7):

The only log I remember, that contains installation success/failure info is the one that can be accessed via ADB (android debug bridge). The command is:

```
adb logcat
```

But you might not have the Android debugging tools installed, so an easy way of looking at the logcat is to install [aLogcat](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd) from market. Because that log is a memory buffer ([I learned it form stackverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424544/where-are-android-logcat-files-stored)).

Man, I sure want an easier way to get that info, but this is the only method I can remember.