# ICS upgrade - Contacts freezing on Galaxy S2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2

This morning I upgraded my Galaxy S2 from Android v2 to ICS, using `Settings/About/Software Update`.  Since doing so, I am encountering a problems with my Contacts, which crashes practically every time I open it.  Major downer, not to be able to look up my contacts, as I'm sure you can imagine.

(I also have a problem with Hebrew fonts, which no longer display correctly - but I've opened a separate question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/ics-messes-up-hebrew-text-display-on-galaxy-s2) to deal with that.)

I have tried doing a factory reset, as suggested in one of the answers, which I originally accepted, because it seemed Contacts were working OK right after the reset - but later, after the rest of my apps were automatically downloaded and reinstalled, the same problem started happening again.

Are there any apps that are known to conflict with Contacts in ICS?  Everything worked fine when I was on Android 2.  Any other ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have a look at the [log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log) It may provide a hint.

Comment: @Flow - nice idea... I downloaded CatLog... but now what?  There's so much noise in that log, I don't know what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to backup as much as possible and then factory reset the phone. This gives you a fresh start, so that alone might resolve your problems, or if they still occur after the factory reset you know they're not caused by any data or applications that didn't survive the upgrade to well.

Comment: That's rather drastic.  Isn't there a less invasive way of diagnosing the problem?

Comment: Also, if I backup before hard-reset, will I be able to get my phone back the way it was by restoring, including all apps, or will it just restore the contacts, memos etc of the native apps?

Comment: It depends on which app you use to backup. Titanium backup for example can backup almost anything, but you need root access. But, factory resetting isn't necessarily as drastic as you think with good measures. Your contacts can be synced with Google and / or Facebook, so you won't lose them. Gmail, Calendar and a lot of apps are all synced remotely as well. Your previously installed apps can be found in the 'My apps' list in the Market application. For other important data, which isn't synced remotely, you might need to find an app that can backup this particular data.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to remove individual apps and then restarting the phone, you might be able to find the culprit by doing this. I think it's more likely however that it's caused by a conflict in the Android's system preferences.

Comment: +1 - factory reset did fix the problem with the contacts freezing, and all my apps are automatically reinstalling, which is really cool.  The problem with Hebrew text is still there, though.  I'll give you answer credit for solving the most important problem, and open a new question to deal with the Hebrew issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Ooh-er... no, scratch that.  Suddenly it's started freezing again.  Clearly there's some app that is conflicting with Contacts, which hadn't downloaded yet when I said Contacts had stopped freezing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove apps one by one, as I mentioned earlier. If you want to know if an app does something with your contacts, you can check it on the Apps detail view under the permissions.

Comment: In my case it was Skype.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this problem for me was **uninstalling skype**.

Skype creates a new group in contacts which for some reason this causes the issue (it used to work before the upgraded).

Comment: I thought this had nailed the problem, but then it came back, even after I uninstalled Skype. :-(  +1 anyway

Comment: @Shaul Hmm.. Do you have any other apps that have access to contacts? Might be worth trying to uninstall those too.

Answer (score -1):

Go into messages (SMS).

Then enter settings (inside the messages SMS app).

Then scroll down to input mode. Change it to Automatic.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I was already on "Automatic" input mode... and this problem is still persisting.  I've basically given up on ever using my contact book.  When I want to look up a contact, I use the dialler to start entering their name, and that searches quickly enough.