# ICS messes up Hebrew text display on Galaxy S2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, hebrew

Follow up from [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23796/15645)... I just installed ICS on my Galaxy S2, and now the Hebrew display is messed up - the *nekudot* are displayed slightly to the left of the letter to which they are supposed to apply.  In my previous question I already did a hard reset, so that's not the answer.

Here's a screenshot where you can see clearly how all the *nekudot* are shifted to the left:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @BryanDenny - Hm... looks like that's another problem that's been introduced - I can't take screen shots anymore.  Tried Power+Home, tried Volume+Power, even tried volume+Home.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, just tried again - Power+volume seems to work... but you've really got to work hard to get the timing right... will post screen shot asap.

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? Maybe it's a font issue? I don't know Hebrew but I'm assuming you mean the dots around the letters are slightly shifted? Can you maybe give a comparison as to what they should look like?

Comment: What app are you looking at that text in? (Is it a siddur app or something like that or are you viewing that text in a text editor)

Comment: @BryanDenny - No custom ROM.  Yes, *nekudot* are dots and other vowel symbols, which are supposed to be inside, directly over or directly under the letter.  I don't know what font issue it might be; all I know is that under Android 2, everything worked fine, and the minute I "upgraded" to ICS the Hebrew fonts got messed up.

Comment: @someoneHuman - Yes, this is a siddur app (Tfilon).  I have several other Hebrew apps, including OYW (On Your Way - ובלכתך בדרך), which has the same display issues.  Interestingly, when I change the font in Tfilon to "System", it works fine, but when I use Ezra (my preferred font), the *nekudot* are messed up like this.

Comment: @Shaul, it sounds like your system Hebrew support is fine. But the Ezra font (which many apps use instead of the system stuff for displaying Hebrew) may not be working correctly on ICS.

Comment: @someoneHuman - It's not just the Ezra font.  I haven't found any font other than System that **does** work on ICS.  That's a pretty major bummer for Hebrew users.