# Droid Charge SCH-I510 Memory Dump Crash

Tags: crashes, samsung-droid-charge

I am a Android developer who has been noticing horrible performance and memory dumps that are crashing my Droid Charge SCH-i510. Besides the lack of roadmap for the phone ( because obviously they are targeting newer models) I know it will never really be updated again.

<del>But I would like to see if any one else is having these issues and if they were able to pin point it.</del> Does anyone know how to solve this issue or overcome it? Obviously not everyone will have the exact same issues. 
But I notice the issue when processing images as well when a specific thread is chewing resources.

I reached out to Samsung and I was told to "Not have a lot of apps installed on the phone" or to "Not use so many apps on the phone" I tried to explain to them that Android when not using an app has a lifecycle that will free up resources from apps not being used so that it will not run out of resources. They just responded to that as "We are sorry you are mad"

Great job helping your dev's pin point an issue.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ]. "I just wanted to kind of see...", "I would like to see what everyone thinks..." and "Thoughts, feelings, other complaints?" are **not** the kind of questions which work here. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: I updated my question to fit your changes. However maybe I was not descriptive enough. I need peoples thoughts and feelings about what they did to solve the mem dump issues. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You're still basically asking for discussion. You should ask about a solution to a specific problem.

Comment: How is this possible? I am asking to see if people could pin point the problem. I in a situation where my main development device is acting up. I need a solution not a discussion.

Comment: Ask a specific question. Don't ask "anybody else having issues".

Comment: I'd suggest you might probably want to ask for how to detect which app is at fault.

Comment: Maybe get rid of your current firmware? http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why this is happening. The problem is due too a bug that most other Android users are having running 2.3.5 and higher. It happens when more than 50 apps are installed on the SD Card. To which it seems there is no work around for as of yet.

So we are stuck ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Search the [logcats](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log) for stack traceback. Try uninstalling apps one at a time, to see if the problem disappears when you uninstalled a certain app.

If the issue come from an installed application, then you should uninstall that app and/or contact the developer to fix the crash.

If the issue is system level, then there is not much you can do. You can either downgrade to a version that crashes less, or try upgrading to custom ROM, although with custom ROMs the crashes could also get worse.

It should be noted that newer Android versions have better application management than older versions. I recalled that there is an improvement that comes either in 2.1 or 2.2 or 2.3 that significantly improves the way the out-of-memory killer works.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I doubt highly that it has much to do with the apps that are installed. I think what you are trying to suggest is to see if any app has a process or thread that is causing the issue. 

Having looked I don't think log cat is the correct place for this because you can't actually see the heap memory.The DDMS maybe a better solution because I could  actually look at memory allocation to apps and see where isn't getting repurposed when not in use.

I feel like this is going to be a ROM issue which is what I was worried about. Which like you said I need a new rom.Thanks

Comment: @chenger: I guess the inevitable question is that, what makes you so sure that it's not an installed app? If it is a ROM issue and you have a stock ROM, then you should be able to find many people on the internet having the same issue.

Comment: @Ryan: Because having done some research on this. Many other Charge users are having this issue. On numerous Charge forums Verizon and it's subsidiaries are suggesting they are " Working on a fix for all the problems" this. They came out with a patch that is supposed to clear up lots of these issues but the plain fact is it just dosen't. If it were infact a memory leak from a app I would be able to trace the memory stack back to the culprit. As of right now I am not seeing that. Thanks