# How active should I expect my Jelly Bean system log file to be?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, logging

When using [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) to view my Android log files, I find very few messages showing up in any of the views.

Selecting Verbose level and no filter, I see that *Main* contains mostly garbage collection debug and info messages, but I rarely more than about 20 messages every minute. *Events* mostly contains info log messages from alogcat itself, at about the same rate, while *Radio* remains steadfastly empty.

Being relatively new to Android, I wonder whether this is normal. Is this rate typical of the main system log file on Jelly Bean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not very active if you use apps like aLogcat. [The permissions system regarding to logs was changed with Jelly Bean: The permission to read logs "READ_LOGS" is now systemOrSignature,](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html) which means that an app that is not signed with the ROM/system key can only view its own log. You can still view the full android log with `adb logcat` from the SDK.

<sup>[I think that this was a long overdue change in the log system.](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html)</sup>

Comment: Thanks flow, that has helped me to [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28853/4229) my other [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27586/4229).