# How can I access android log files on my Nexus 7 without root access?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, logging, nexus-7

Since [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) now [no longer works with Jelly Bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28848/4229), how can I access the system log files on my device without either root access or attaching it to a computer?

I [have tried](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28853/4229) using `adb logcat` from my PC and that worked fine, so I know that plenty of messages are being logged.

Using `logcat` from [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) on my Nexus 7 shows almost no output though and `adb logcat` from *Android Terminal Emulator*, starts the daemon but then just says `- waiting for device -` and nothing more appears.

So, is it possible to access android log files on my Nexus 7 **without root access**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems accessing message logs on Jelly Bean with aLogcat](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/problems-accessing-message-logs-on-jelly-bean-with-alogcat)

Comment: @Izzy - The point of this question is that all of the solutions in my other question (which I linked to in this question) require root access. While these solutions are useful to those who have rooted their devices, I wanted a more specific solution for those who haven't rooted their device.

Comment: You may find [PhoneHome](http://mattspitz.me/2013/12/05/phonehome-remote-logging-for-android.html) worth a look

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, for security reasons it is not possible to access android log files on the Nexus 7 (or any other device running Jelly Bean or higher) without root access. Google changed that with Jelly Bean.

I'd suggest you wait until logcat readers like aLogCat and such get fixed (i.e. they will require root access to show all logs then).

From [AISEC-TR-2012-001-Android-OS-Security.pdf - 3.3 Android Permission Model](http://www.aisec.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/aisec/Dokumente/Publikationen/Studien_TechReports/deutsch/AISEC-TR-2012-001-Android-OS-Security.pdf):

> The READ_LOGS permission can substitute the following on many devices,
>   depending on the Android version and thus the standard apps’ versions
>   installed:
>
> - READ_CONTACTS
> - GET_TASKS – every started Activity is listed in the system’s logs
> - READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS – opening new web pages is a browser Activity and thus logged
> - READ_SMS

**All solutions below require root access**:

You need to either run logcat as root in a shell or manually grant it via the shell pm command (root required) works also (see [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1793465%EF%BB%BF), exchange *org.jtb.alogcat.donate* with the app's pkg name):

`pm grant org.jtb.alogcat.donate android.permission.READ_LOGS`

This is for the lazy ones and **not** suggested:
If you're desperate, careless and lazy, you can fix it by giving every app the READ_LOGS permission by applying this ugly and **insecure** hack ([Chainfire via twitter](https://twitter.com/ChainfireXDA/status/237078791804051456)):

`chmod 04755 /system/bin/logcat`

To quote CyanogenMod developer Koushik Dutta's G+ [post](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/2Yb5wgrx5ib):

> Did the Android Log permissions/behavior change in JellyBean?
>
> It seems that if an application runs "logcat" now, it can see only the log entries created by its UID. Log lines from other UIDs are not shown. Basically, it seems to be filtered now.
>
> I have the same permissions as usual. Also confirmed the same thing is happening in other log collector apps.

Comment: There's no way without root of which I know of. For the sake of security. Starting with JellyBean, the read_logs permission doesn't have to be granted anymore (each app can only view it's own logs anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the link to xda, I integrated that.

Comment: Thanks for adding in the `pm grant` option. Note that as I now say in [my other answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28853/4229), you need to specify a slightly different package if you aren't using the *donate* version of *aLogcat*: `pm grant org.jtb.alogcat android.permission.READ_LOGS`

Comment: The referenced paper does to explain how `READ_LOGS` is equal to `READ_CONTACTS` on some platforms. I guess the mean that some apps put contact data in the logs, but that's not really the same as `READ_CONTACTS`. But then I'd say that the paper is written in a alarmist tone.

Comment: READ_LOGS leaks a lot more information than just contact data. There's the user's name, probably gmail address, locations, installed apps (app usage even) and so on. Plus: it has been used to read and extract addresses from stack dumps of system daemons in the pre ASLR days by root exploits. Now that they're switched off on a big part (4.1±) you may get swarm protection (compare it to not vaccinating your child in a disease free vaccinated population). Problems  loomed and Google did the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by this though it would explain some things.

Running the same app on my nexus7 and my galaxy nexus, both on jellybean,  the phone sees log output from all apps, the tablet doesn't. This would say that it's not jellybean its the nexus7. Backing this up, I've just checked and they both have different kernels. The tablet, with a newer one.

Maybe its the updated kernel that, means logs don't appear.

Guess I'll have to root after all: (

Comment: That's interesting Russ, thanks for the extra information.

Comment: Actually I've now been reliably informed that its because the app I am using to see the logs, was installed on my machine when I had ICS so it's retained the permissions to see the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed [a Logcat app](https://github.com/tananaev/rootless-logcat) that uses alternative approach. It utilizes remote debugging feature. You need to enable it on the phone first, but it has to be done only once and then you can use the app to retrieve all logs.