# How do I get the log files on my Optima Smart 220?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, logging

I want to access the log files of my tablet (Optima Smart 220, running 4.1.1 Jelly Bean).

Also, how do I root this device so I can get the log files?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! The question-and-answer format of this site works best if you put each question in a separate question post. The "how do I get logs" part of your question is answered by http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/problems-accessing-message-logs-on-jelly-bean-with-alogcat For information about rooting, have a look at [the 'rooting' tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need root to access log files.

One option is to use the adb tool from the Android SDK. But it's a huge download.

Another option is to use a tool like [LogShark](https://gist.github.com/hrj/5983971).

(disclaimer: I created it)