# Chrome failed during startup with an unexpected error

Tags: chrome-for-android

When starting Chrome on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 3, I just get the following error message, and no error code.

> Chrome failed during startup with an unexpected error.

Googling the above phrase gives me one result.  I have no idea how to approach this. I have cleared all application data, restarted my phone multiple times, and no luck.

Any insight and fix for this?

Comment: I would recommend [logcat](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28853/96277) to do the [tag:logging] when you start chrome and until you see the error. See what does it tell, and post the log to Pastebin so that we can also see it.

Comment: Update: I removed chrome and re-installed it, so I guess we'll never know what it was...

Comment: I can **reproduce this error if I go into setting>apps>chrome ....
and then select move to sd card.** Of course you then have to open Chrome to get the error. If I move the app back to internal memory the error goes away. Uninstall/Reinstalling Chrome installs it to internal memory by default so that would also make the error go away and sense of what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Apps -> Chrome -> Clear cache, and also Move it to phone memory, in case it is on the SD card.

Answer (score -1):

please try clearing you profile, local state, and flags? Android Settings > Apps > All Apps > Chrome > Clear app data
@This way worked for me@

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer giving details ? In the present state, it looks more like a comment

Comment: OP wrote: *"I have cleared all application data"*.

Comment: I have MediaPad 10 FHD and this setting worked for my tablet i have cleared chrome app data and worked correctly @ if you have cleared and don't work correctly you can install chrome beta app from google play here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta&hl=en