# How can I install an app if I have inconsistent UIDs and the market app crashes?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I am having [issues](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28488/1261) with inconsistent UIDs. Trying to understand what was going on, I got the [advice](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28522/1261) to install a terminal emulator.

The problem is that when I go to the Market app, I receive a (very fast) error message, which says that the process `com.android.vending` is not working.

How can I then install one of the apps that have been suggested to me?

Comment: Have you tried any of the "usual steps" on a misbehaving playstore issue (purging the cache of the playstore app and things like that)? Try following the google-play-store tag below your question (and further narrow down the results) to find additional suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Izzy, I had tried to factory-reset the phone without success. As far as you know, does the reset purge the caches, too, or not? I have in the meanwhile got a new phone...

Comment: Factory reset is, simply speaking, wiping everything which is mounted r/w: Data, caches, etc. Basically, only `/system` (and of course recovery + radio image) are left untouched. If a factory-reset does not cure a bug, that bug has feet (i.e. must be a hardware issue) or is located in the "System ROM". So flashing a different ROM (stock or custom) could cure it in your case. Or have the vendor/producer taking it back for repair.