# My android tablet is not working

Tags: data-monitoring

My RCA tablet screen says UID'S are inconsistent need to wipe data partition that is all it will do i've let battery run down that is the only way to turn off it is an RCA 7 Mercury. help please

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28488/inconsistent-uids-and-wiping-a-data-partition

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter the recovery and perform a factory reset.

Have the tablet powered off first and make sure you have more than 50% charge on the battery. Boot into recovery mode by pressing and holding the volume up and power buttons. At the RCA logo screen, let go of the volume up button and you should next see an android image. Press and hold the power button and tap the volume up button once more and you will be brought to the recovery mode menu. From here, you will need to use your volume up and down buttons to scroll and navigate to the wipe data/factory reset option and use the power button to confirm. When the process is done, go ahead and reboot and your tablet will be set to factory original settings.

Comment: I can't get any screen up to enter anything when the message comes up to wipe partition it is only there for a second then goes back to RCA sorta blinking then repeats message over and over I hope I'm explaining good enough I am ready to throw it in the Gulf of Mexico  my patience is gone

Comment: I am charging now when it 's charged I will do it. Thank you