# Where are the developer options in Android 4.2?

Tags: settings, usb-debugging, 4.2-jelly-bean

I wanted to access the developer options to enable adb access on Android 4.2 but cannot find it.

How can I enable that?

Once I've activated the menu, how can I hide it again?

Comment: ...and any idea how to hide them again?

Comment: @pelms You should ask this in a new question.

Comment: @Flow: Is this really worth its own question? Besides this: Not sure you can do this, at least I haven't found a way to do so using the UI.

Comment: Since asking questions is free, yes. The voting process will then decide if it's a good question. And I would upvote such a question.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Starting with Android 4.2. *developer options* are hidden by default to clean up the options menu. They're nice for debugging but some overlay options may be very alienating for average users when they're accidentially enabled.

> On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default.
>   To make it available, go to *Settings -> About phone* and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

You see a popup hat reads *You are now a developer* when it was successful.

Source: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

It's not possible to hide it again unless you're root and delete this file:

```
/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/development.xml
```

EDIT: According to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38148/15713) answer it's also possible to just delete the App data of the *Settings* app (com.android.settings, located at *Settings->Apps->All->Settings->Clear data*).

Comment: Update: According to this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/38148/15713) it's possible to delete the **settings** app data (if you're willing to sacrifice other settings, of course)

Comment: Deleting the settings app data doesn't wipe your settings.  To wipe all the settings, you'd need to wipe out the data from the "settings storage" app, though (on my GS3 anyway), it won't let you do that.

Comment: A factory reset might do it? :P

Comment: Sure, but that seems to be a 'little' overkill...

Comment: What else does deleting the settings app do? I'm surprised you can't tap the build number seven times to hide it or anything like that.

Comment: Video showing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLQ7CZeMEVA