# Hide Developer Options in Android 4.2

Tags: settings, 4.2-jelly-bean

I know how to [show the developer options menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33496/where-are-the-developer-options-in-android-4-2). How do I hide it again?

Comment: In the given answer, ce4 says it is not possible to hide it again without root access http://android.stackexchange.com/a/33497/25403 And with root, the solution is given

Comment: I have to admit that I updated my answer after seing this question... :-) Forgot to compile an answer here as well, but Compro01 already did that ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clearing the data on the "settings" app will get rid of the developer options on the Galaxy Nexus (at least on 4.1.  Not sure about 4.2), but that may only work on that device.  It doesn't do it on my Galaxy S3.

**Note**: The above action clears the *settings* of the settings app, i.e. not actually importanty data per se. You should be fine doing this.

The only other known method to get rid of them requires root and deleting **/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/development.xml**.
See [Where are the developer options in Android 4.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33496/where-are-the-developer-options-in-android-4-2)

Comment: Clearing data for Settings did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: New CM10.1 added a feature to hide developer options when it is turned off**.

[GitCode](https://github.com/cyanogenmod/android_packages_apps_Settings/commit/6b1dbff0aa2dad9929e3f2167dc95ee0ccf0e54a)

Once you became developer you can't hide developer options from your mobile. But you can simply turn it off (Developer option will be there in Settings).

Comment: Not true, see Compro01's answer.

Comment: He's right, if someone is not willling to delete the **settings** which happen to contain other stuff besides the visibility of the devel options menu as well and the phone is not rooted.

Comment: @ce4 - The app data for the "settings" app only contains the settings for the settings app, not the general settings for everything else, which are contained in the "settings storage" app, and you can't clear the data on that via the GUI.

Comment: @Compro01 Thanks! Should have read the source or examine the data in advance before posting. Edited the other answer