# Developer options for a second user on Android 4.3

Tags: settings, 4.3-jelly-bean, multi-user

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) edition with Jelly Bean and set up several user accounts. I have enabled developer options on one account (clicking Settings::About tablet::Build number 7 times) and everything is working as it should.

Now I would like to enable developer options on a different user account. However, no matter how many times I click the Build number field, the Developer Options refuses to appear.

Is there a way to enable Developer Options on another account? Is there a way to switch Developer Options from one account to another?

(I have tried [clearing settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38123/hide-developer-options-in-android-4-2) in the account with developer options. It did remove developer options, but it still didn't allow developer options in the second account).

Comment: Just to confirm, is it a new user / account, or a new restricted profile?

Comment: This is a full user (*not* a restricted account). Cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only the main user (owner) has access to `Developer Options`.

**Related question:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable

Comment: Thanks for finding the duplicate. If no-one else has a solution or workround where developer options are made available, I'll award you the +50 bounty.