# How to enable developer settings Nexus 7 4.4.2 kit kat

Tags: settings, nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat

I have the old Nexus 7 with stock 4.4.2, and I want to enable developer settings.

I have found many references to Settings -> About (Tablet) -> And click 7 times on build number - but that simply does not work. I have tried tapping it 1 million times and nothing happens. If I tap "Android Version 4.4.2" in the same menu, I get the whole spinning K, kitkat, easter-egg game etc.

What am I missing? How do I enable developer settings?

Comment: Possibly covered by [Developer options for a second user on Android 4.3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/53837)

Answer (score 8):

Apparently only the tablet owner (first user created) has access to developer settings. I was using another user.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable