# Nexus 10 handwriting apps always lag

Tags: hardware, performance, notes, stylus, samsung-nexus-10

So I just bought a nexus 10 and among the many reasons for getting one, I want to take notes with it. I've bought myself a nice stylus that works wonderfully on iPads and my galaxy nexus phone. However, writing with the same stylus and exact same apps on my nexus 10 isn't working as one would hope. It seems to lag quite badly in picking up where my stylus is and this forces me to write very slowly so that it will pick up all of my strokes, thus making it pretty much useless in a classroom setting, but, like I said before, I don't see this at all with my galaxy nexus.


So, why am I seeing such a huge difference in performance between these two devices when (I assume) the nexus 10 would be so much more powerful than my phone? Is it the apps or the hardware? And how do I fix this issue without just writing my own note taking app?

Comment: Compare the processor & memory of the devices, since a faster processor & more RAM could make a lot of difference in recognition rate and accuracy. Another difference could be the resolution of the capacitive touchscreen panel, and quality of it's drivers etc. In a nutshell, even from same vendor (i.e. Samsung), 2 devices might use very different hardware peripherals.

Comment: @icarus74 Yes, one of my thoughts would be the difference in screens...perhaps while an app is configured to work really well with a phone's screen, it might not be for a tablet? I wouldn't know differences would cause this though.

Comment: Do you see the same poor performance with other styli? Does the Nexus 10 respond as well to physical touch with your finger as the iPad and Galaxy Nexus? When testing the stylus as you described, did you rest your hand on the screen or keep it lifted off (leaving just the tip of the stylus touching)? Just thinking these factors could help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: @Mr.Buster I do see the same preformance regardless of the stylus used as well as with physical touch. I did not rest my hand on the screen. I agree with you...these are factors to consider and I have considered them...just neglected to post them in my question I guess. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: @Brandon If all touch interaction with the N10 is laggy then it would be time to consider OS-wide stuff. If you factory reset, does it still lag? (Could be an app causing resource scarcity). Enable "Show Touches" in [Developer options](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/11343); do you see a lag in the registering of your touch (the appearance of the glow where your finger or the stylus touches) or in the OS' response to it (e.g. slow home screen animation)?

Comment: @Mr.Buster not all touch is laggy on the device to my eye. I have actually already tried the show touches  thing, it seems that the touch sensitivity is the same through out the device including writing on these note apps. However, the responsiveness that one needs when writing seems to need to be much greater than that needed for swiping and poking apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make device as root
2. Go to [xda-developers.com - Seeder Topic](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1987032)
3. Install last Seeder apk on your device
4. Run it

And then your device should work better.

Comment: While it seems to work for some people, AOSP project members deny it can do anything good. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42265

Comment: @Cthulhu would you like to delete my post?

Comment: After a lot of testing, I realized that the stylus that I had was messed up for some reason, I had actually accidentally bought the first generation version of the stylus. After buying the new stylus things improved greatly...but the Seeder app makes the difference in the end.

Comment: @Brandon: Thanks for your post; quite helpful to me since I'm going to buy a Nexus 10 and want to have handwriting recognition work smoothly. So, what was the manufacturer and model number of the newer stylus that you purchased?

Comment: @bgoodr I bought an adonit jot pro (Official Page: http://adonit.net/jot/pro/ Amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Adonit-Stylus-iPhone-Kindle-Tablets/dp/B00931K1QK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1368459007&sr=8-1&keywords=adonit+jot+pro&tag=toofyoga-20). I will warn you though, I am still seeing a lag at times, don't know if it's because of the stylus, the app (Using lecture notes pro...best one I could find for android), or the device. This stylus is really geared towards iPads and seems to work better on them. but I really like that it feels like a real pen.You also will NEED a screen protector. scratches