# LG G2 - Debugging mode not enabled

Tags: usb-debugging

I'm attempting to run an app on the LG G2 (Verizon) using Eclipse on a Mac. The phone, however, is not recognized by the computer. I enabled debugging but it doesn't appear when I do `adb devices`. Additionally, I never receive the debugging notification when I put the phone in debugging mode. I think it's the phone since I've ran other devices on the mac with no problems.

Any suggestions on why the debugging mode is not being enabled?

Comment: Have you installed drivers for your phone?

Comment: It's a mac; drivers are not needed. I placed the connection to internet when connected to USB. For some reason, only that USB settings enables debug mode

Comment: Having the same problem. Tried multiple cables, including the one that came with the phone and that works for charging in fast mode.

Comment: Could this be the same problem as http://android.stackexchange.com/q/53554/12442 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution: Assuming you have debugging mode enabled, you have to change the USB settings to Internet Connection: Modem or ethernet. Keeping it on Charge Phone, Media Sync, or Camera does not enable debugging.

Comment: Actually you need to run in tethering only once per computer - in order to get the prompt for allowing the connection from the computer. After you give permanent rights of access you can develop in charging mode too.

Comment: Only way I got USB debugging to work was to select Send images (PTP).  Charge tablet and Media sync(MPT) did not work.

Comment: I follow @ono answer and also found the solution. I had to follow three steps: 1) In settings/general/about phone/common/software info, click 7 times in build number; 2) In general/developer options, turn on usb debugging; 3) In network/tethering&networks, turn on usb tethering.

Comment: I had this same problem in an LG Leon. You have to pick "PTP" as  @user129894 said, nothing else worked!

Answer (score 4):

The user44860 answer is almost correct. Goto Settings, About Phone, Software Information:

Click Build Number **7 times**. You should see a message saying that *now you're a developer*.

So, you can go back and enabe USB Debugging in the Development Settings.

Maybe you've to detach the usb cable, enable the debug and re-plug the usb cable.

Answer (score 2):

on the G2 goto Settings: About Phone: Software Information: Click Build Number 5 times. Go back and choose Development Settings Enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 1):

Try another usb2 cable. I had the same issues with the S2 after a while it gives me Unknown Device, even if before was known. Try another cable and see if is being recognized. As well it has to be on MTP ( media device ) and not PTP (camera).

Also you could try another thing: while your phone is connected disable debugging mode and enable it back. Also could try restarting your adb.

Comment: disable / enable debugging mode helps me.  Otherwise the 'USB debugging' mode was disabled all the time.