# How to fix "error: device not found" when I try to use ADB

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I'm trying to get my phone (JiaYu G3T) working under adb on Windows 8 x64 (worked fine on Windows 7 x64 before reinstalling my OS).

Driver Android Composite ADB Interface, version 8.0.0.0, works fine.

My adb won't list any devices (`adb.exe devices`).

I tried:

- installed Google USB driver
- enabled debugging mode in phone
- added my device's hardware IDs to the Google USB driver inf file and installed
- installed Moborobo (phone works fine in there but adb still won't find the device)
- tried switch Settings > Storage > Menu > USB Computer connection to "Camera (PTP)"
- tried two different version of adb (1.0.31 and 1.0.26)

Those were some of the advices I found so far.

Comment: Maybe you try Koush's [Universal ADB driver](http://adbdriver.com/). In many similar cases, this brought the relief. Unfortunately not in all, but in many at least – so worth a try.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't help, thank you for your help though! It claims that the driver is already installed

Comment: You might have to uninstall the other one first.

Comment: I did and the driver works fine but still no device :/

Comment: Sorry, then I'm out of ideas. I don't use Windows.

Comment: When you say you "enabled debugging mode", might this be the same problem [solved here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/53571/12442)?

Comment: My phone says USB debugging connected, also I didn't really change anything in my phone and it used to work in Win7 two weeks ago. Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works, I'm using the Google USB driver. The problem is that I have to keep killing adb.exe before doing anything really (e.g. building and pushing an apk to the phone), otherwise it can't find the device.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers that come with PdaNet may work. Give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Microsoft User-Mode Driver Framework (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2685813). It will require a restart.

Worked for me, Nexus 5, Windows 7 SP1.

I tried the Google USB Driver (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) but it didn't fix the issue for me. The Microsoft User-Mode Driver Framework, however, did.

Answer (score 0):

While I was able to `adb push` from within android OS, I wasn't in recovery mode.

Turns out the culprit was Cyanogen Bootloader. Once I flashed to TWRP, I could use ADB again from recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (with a Nexus S, but I don't think it matters here). I could manually install the Google driver and it started without reporting problems. Nevertheless, `adb devices` did not list any device. Two things looked suspicious (and are probably related), but I could not use them to get a clue to the solution:

- The hardware ID reported in device manager did not containe the part "&MI_01".
- The driver installer warned me that the driver would not match.

Finally (and just by fluke) I found the solution that worked for me: somehow my Windows 7 installation had lost the files usb.inf and usb.pnf from C:\Windows\inf. I followed the advice in https://superuser.com/a/515823/341332 to repair the issue (basically: find the missing files in c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository and copy them back), then I uninstalled my Nexus S in device manager and reinstalled it. I had to select the Google driver manually again, but this time: no warnings, the hardware ID ends with "&MI_01", and most important: `adb devices` now lists my device :-)

I hope this helps others that get stuck like me.