# No debug icon on Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Tags: usb, debug

When I plug the USB cable, the debug icon doesn't show up. adb devices doesn't see it.

- Developer mode enabled.
- Developer option enabled.
- Stay awake enabled.
- USB debugging enabled.

I am already in developer mode. Yesterday it showed up after insert sim card and reboot but this morning nothing.

I am using Debian 8 and debugging other devices has never been a problem.

I even tried rebooting the PC, and "hard" reboot the smartphone (letting the battery discharge completely) and start it again, but without success.

Comment: Have you tried with different USB cables and/or different USB ports and rebooting the PC?

Comment: I tried different USB cables (known to work with other devices). Tried different USB ports. Plugging other devices on the very same PC always work except for the Nexus 5. I didn't try rebooting my PC but I will.

Comment: Have you actually turned on USB debugging? Simply turning on the "developer options" screen **doesn't** turn on USB debugging. The option for USB debugging is a couple of screens down. [You wouldn't be the first person to get confused by this setting.](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/53554/12442)

Comment: In usb connections settings is it set to charge only mode?

Comment: yes, i also tried mtp, ptp too.

Comment: In charge only mode it will not work but since you have also tried mtp,ptp. Thinking about are the other devices older leading to is your adb.exe up to date? Also maybe try revoking permissions. Maybe somethings up with the udev rules. With the adb devices  is it just blank or does it have a bunch of ??? Or anything.

Comment: adb devices: blank == nothing, no ?????? , i tried also revoking permissions. I don't think it's adb because when plugging the phone, there is no event logged in /var/log/messages nor /var/log/syslog nor in lsusb

Comment: Try downloading the latest android studio and connect.

Comment: Did somebody solve this issue?