# Connect through adb to a Nexus 4 with a broken touch screen?

Tags: adb, broken-screen

I have a Nexus 4 with a broken touch screen from which I would like to recover some files. `adb` is a tool often referred for this purpose, as in [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/guide-data-recovery-broken-screen-t2757257#post65961900).

I have installed `adb` and `fastbook` on my computer and have tried to connect to phone using various methods, but always without success. When I run `adb services` the list always comes out empty.

Browsing through previous questions on this matter, I came across [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/53571/50942) where it is said a certain **USB debugging** feature must be activated in the phone itself to allow the connection from `adb`. Obviously I can not do this since the touch screen is not working.

Is there any other of connecting through `adb` to a Nexus 4 with a broken touch screen?

Comment: Nope. You can use an OTG or Bluetooth mouse, and/or a TV-out adapter. You can also flash custom recovery if you're bootloader unlocked, and use the volume/power keys to navigate a recovery.

Comment: The OTG mouse is a nice tip. Will I be able to draw my screen unlock gesture with it? That would pretty much give me full access to the phone.

Comment: According to [this guide](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-advanced-usb-otg-nexus-4) I would need to root the phone to use an OTG connection; not a way out either. I also do not know how to activate Bluetooth without using the touch screen.

Comment: Dang. I didn't know Google removed it through an OTA update. Still worth a try? Did you consider getting a new screen?

Comment: A screen replacement costs about the double of buying a new phone.

Comment: I would say [about half.](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xnexus+4+screen.TRS0&_nkw=nexus+4+screen&_sacat=0)

Comment: I do not live in the US. And do not have the tools required to do the replacement myself.

Comment: Hint: Check out our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), this topic is covered there.

Comment: Closely related: [How to do a clone / backup & restore between identical devices via USB and broken screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/124068)

Comment: I went through the [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) and could only find two suggestions for this case: 1. Use a software called Kies; 2. Use an OTG USB connection. Kies only runs on Windows and Mac and OTG requires rooting the Nexus 4.

Answer (score -2):

You can access ADB if you install a custom recovery. I would recommend TWRP.

> Note that the following solution requires a Nexus 4 with an unlocked bootloader. To unlock the bootloader you can do a `fastboot oem unlock` – but running that **will wipe the user data as well**.

- Download the [TWRP image for your device](https://dl.twrp.me/mako/) 
  (Download the latest one)
- Power off your phone
- Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> Key and the <kbd>Power</kbd> button at the same time, this will let you boot your device in fastboot mode.
- Move the downloaded TWRP image into the folder where you installed `adb` and `fastboot`, and then rename the downloaded `twrp-X.X.X-X-mako.img` file to "recovery.img". Open the "Command Prompt" in that location.
- Type `fastboot devices` and check whether your computer recognizes your device. If the list the following command returns does not show your device, make sure you have the appropriate ADB Drivers installed.
- Then type in `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` and wait for a SUCCESS message.
- Then type in `fastboot reboot recovery` and your phone should now reboot into recovery mode.

Your phone should now be accessible via ADB

Now you can follow [this guide at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/guide-data-recovery-broken-screen-t2757257).

Comment: How do I power off the phone with a broken touch screen?

Comment: Nearly every phone can be shut down holding the power button for 4 sec or longer.

Comment: I thin you should consider mentioning and stressing the fact that your solution requires a Nexus 4 with an unlocked bootloader, otherwise, the solution would simply not work and would waste a reader's time since a reader might end up thinking that they are doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I muddle through this answer, figuring out how to switch off the phone, that neither `fastboot` nor `adb` get a folder of their own, etc. `fastboot devices` recognises the phone, but the `recovery` command returns the following: "sending 'recovery' (9122 KB)...
OKAY [  0.290s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (remote: not supported in locked device)
finished. total time: 0.291s"

Comment: Firelord: would there be a way to unlock the bootloader?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa yes, there is. Doing `fastboot oem unlock` will unlock the bootloader  but **will wipe the user data as well**.

Comment: Is this only the application data (e.g. notes in the notebook application) or also the files stored in the file system (e.g Donwloads folder).

Comment: i sorry... you would need an unlocked bootloader... @LuísdeSousa ... I am really sorry