# How to change device name for Kindle in Nexus 7 2nd Generation (2013)

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, kindle-for-android

I just got a Nexus 7 2nd Generation (2013) with Android 4.3.

I installed Kindle, and the device shows up named `[my-name]'s Android Tablet`.

In earlier versions of Android, I can go to the About screen and there's a "Device Name" option. It's not on my About screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename from the Amazon website itself:

1. Manage Your Kindle
2. Manage Your Devices
3. Edit (blue link under Edit Kindle Information dialog) > Edit Kindle Information

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That setting was moved to the (hidden) developer options entry.

At first, you need to activate veveloper settings [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33496/where-are-the-developer-options-in-android-4-2), then change your hostname in the debugging section (2nd option group, line 5 in Android 4.3)

Comment: You should probably mention this is only in CyanogenMod, not stock.

Comment: Oh, is it? Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't aware of this.