# Enabling adb on Beaglebone Black

Tags: adb, beaglebone-black

I have successfully loaded TI-Android pre-built image on a BBB which was downloaded from here. Everything works well on the device. I have been trying to enable adb without much luck. Basic HW and SW is as follows

**Hardware**

- Beaglebone black.
- 4DCAPE-43T.
- 5V power supply.
- mini usb connection to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host system.

**Software**

- TI-Android JB **pre-built** image 
  (TI_Android_JB_4.2.2_DevKit_4.1.1_beagleboneblack.tar.gz).
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS host system.

On the BBB I have turned on USB debugging by

```
App Launcher" -> "Settings" -> "Developer options"
```

On the Host side

lsusb output is

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a52 Importek
```

/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0451", MODE="0666"
```

I have executed the following two command

- chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
- sudo service udev restart

When I do an

```
adb devices
```

I don't see the BBB, but when I have HTC phone attached I do see a valid response.

What I am doing wrong?

Also I plug the mini-usb to the host machine. Is this correct? Or do I have connect to the serial debugging port.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the entries in your `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` are correct? I see no matching device in your `lsusb` output. Shouldn't that be the one called "Importek"? And shouldn't the file then contain the vendorID from that one?

Comment: See also my answer on [Configuring ADB for Nexus 4 on Ubuntu 11.10](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39431/16575) for details.

Comment: I was able to get adb with an Android JB image that I built. I was not able to get adb working with TI pre-built image. Shall post more data in due course.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the vendor IDs you've added to the udev rules file correspond to a device listed by `lsusb`. [Other sources on the net](http://github.jfet.org/BBKNotes1.html) suggest that the correct device ID is `SYSFS{idVendor}=="1d6b", SYSFS{idProduct}="0104"`, but this device doesn't appear in your `lsusb` output either. Run `lsusb` with the device unplugged and plugged in to find which device is the right one, and edit your udev rules appropriately.

To confirm: you **don't** want to connect to the serial debugging port to get `adb` to work.

Comment: When I run Angstrom, and do lsusb I see SYSFS{idVendor}=="1d6b". But when I run Android (of the uSD card) and do a lsusb I don't see SYSFS{idVendor}=="1d6b". Also in android I have to always enable USB debugging options. On other android devices when I enable USB debugging it stays enabled all the time.

Comment: Is there something unique in JB to enable debugging options.

Comment: [Yes, here's how to enable the developer options in Jellybean.](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/12442)

Comment: I did this part, each time I restart Android on BBB the debugging is disabled. Aslo there appears the be know issue per http://code.google.com/p/rowboat/wiki/JellybeanOnBeaglebone_WithSGX