# How to turn on USB connection to PC

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers

I bought a KingSing K5 Android phone, and there doesn't seem to be an option for turning on USB connection to PC (to transfer files). I have the Google USB driver installed on the PC, but when I connect nothing happens. Is there a specific way to turn on USB connection in Android 4.2.2?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/23414

Comment: @AlexP. The question you linked is about turning on ADB, whereas as the questioner here wants to "transfer files", I think the question is more likely about MTP.

Answer (score -1):

you just have to enable usb debugging mode.
go to settings scroll down to developer options. Under that the first option is  usb debugging. enable that

Comment: OP wants to use **USB storage**  not USB debugging.