# App continues to consume battery long after its closed

Tags: battery

I use tunein radio app in the morning.  After my use, I close it via exit button, and don't use it for rest of the day.

But hours after the use, I have observed it draining over 10% of my battery. I have tried options like force stop, and even reboot - but issue still persists. Notifications for this app are turned off. No other alarms / reminders set.

I'm on kitkat 4.4.4 / CyanogenMod 11s

Comment: is the Application use any Service?

Comment: As Brasil suggested you freeze, and defrost it. Also you can remove it from startup list to avoid slow bootup and auto starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way-
Install AIO Toolbox, its a nice tool, freely available. From there remove the app from startup/boot list. Use your radio app only when you need. Also you have to clean up your memory on regular interval for refreshing RAM.

**Update:**
**Not sure but might be a help.**
Download JRummy Rom Toolbox and from there goto StartUp Manager. From there You can see the threads opened by the radio app. Disable all threads. I am not sure , If free version of the app has feature as I am using paid version, downloaded from BlackMart.

Comment: While your answer doesn't completely address my question, i found AIO toolbox very helpful. Its well designed, efficient, and versatile. Thanks heaps! ( Just one caution - while cleaning memory, we should uncheck 'process' clean up to avoid losing account data. )

Answer (score 2):

Ending the application by "closing it" may kill the process, but it may have several services running. I'm on my phone, so I cannot add the references, but having multiple apps in memory isn't that bad- I don't think it really effects the life of your battery.

In this instance, if you think (or know) that a particular application is being a pain, I would suggest you first download the application "Watchdog". This gives detailed information about applications, and then let's you kill them when they become too consuming. Watchdog is very good for analysing the running services. If you do find your application is misbehaving, then you have a problem.

If Watchdog does not mark the application as misbehaving, then we may need to dig deeper. If possible, try to run tasker with an automated script to kill the services of this application, which should in turn kill all instances. Whether this is what you want, or is safe, is another question.

One thing to take into consideration is did the application consume so much when your phone was not rooted? Perhaps SU has removed the restrictions the application once had..

Comment: So the native android battery usage indicator is not very reliable?

Comment: @pat_nafs No, that's not what I mean. I'm saying whilst you're killing the instance/process, there are always services running. The 10% usage may be because Tune In has a streaming services or update that's continually polling the server/app for you. Think of it like a custom launcher- go launcher. When you double tap home, you do not get an option to kill Go Launcher- but it's there. This is because applications have services that run in the background doing tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and classifications. I will download watchdog and update here. By the way, my device is one plus one, running on CyanogenMod by default.

Comment: Awesome. If you have continual problems, please upload some screenshots of the battery statistics so we can review them. You may want to review the CyanogemMod webpage for possible issues..

Comment: I downloaded watchdog and I've been using it for 4 days now but it did not raise any flags for this app automatically (while running or in the background. It did however, raise flag for the guardian app.)
While the application was still consuming 5% battery as per the indicator, I decided to go for the kill option in watchdog. 
I did this both for the app and services. I checked battery indicator again in 10 mins. It was still consuming the same amount. Thankfully, I found the alternate solution that I am posting below.

Answer (score 1):

Use Greenify for hibernating your tunein radio,this works fine for most apps.
If it not works properly,  need to freeze the app using ROM toolbox and then defrost when needed.
I am using this method mainly for Facebook,truecaller,google play services which consumes more battery usage.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following delete option in the battery usage status tool:

[image]

Note that it is different from REFRESH button. I clicked on it and bam! Here are the new usage stats:

[image]

As it can be seen, this button basically killed on other apps except essential android services. (Correct me if I am wrong, but I think it is CM11 specific feature. I would like to know more about exactly what it does and if it is reasonably safe to do it daily. Will google /check CM website / forums and update here)

Comment: See mu updated answer....

Answer (score 0):

I second [Basil Then's suggestion](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82984/5132) to use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify). It's meant for exactly this kind of situation, and it's really easy to use. It does require root, but you already have that since you're on CyanogenMod.

Another option that's already built into CyanogenMod that might help is a feature called App Ops that was [briefly part of stock Android but removed](http://www.cnet.com/news/why-android-wont-be-getting-app-ops-anytime-soon/). This feature is still part of CyanogenMod, and you can access it by going to *Settings* → *Privacy* → *Privacy Guard*. From there you can scroll down to TuneIn (or any other app) and long-press it to control specific permissions. There are a few that will directly affect battery life, such as *Keep awake* and *Wake up*.

One other option that's also built into CyanogenMod: go to *Settings* → *Developer options* ([enable Developer options](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/33497/5132) first if you don't see it) then scroll all the way to the bottom and check *Kill app back button*. Now when you're done using TuneIn you can long-press the back button and it should kill it.

Since each app is different (some run as a service, some wake up the phone repeatedly, some keep it awake), you may need to try more than one of these options, and it might even be a combination of them that ends up doing what you want.