# Huawei G6 no longer enable USB debugging

Tags: usb-debugging, huawei

My Huawei G6 can no longer detected by my computer. My phone charges but doesn't show any USB debugging in the notification bar. I tried many USB cables but it just charges. Any options how to debug my phone? Help!!!

Comment: Try other USB-Ports on your computer

Comment: I already tried it too. :(

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the driver?

Comment: That phone runs android 4.3 so developer options hidden. (starting android 4.2_) to unhide read www.droidviews.com/how-to-hide-developer-options-on-android-devices/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the developer options in Android 4.2?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33496/where-are-the-developer-options-in-android-4-2)

Comment: ever found a solution to this? having the same issue and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Clicking 7 times on the Build Number (found under About Phone) will give you Developer privileges.

This must be a feature to prevent kids or people who don't know what they are doing from enabling the Developer Mode.

I can confirm this works for the Huawei 560 as well.

Watch this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7swUjZm7y6c

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question, or include the details within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that USB debugging is enabled under Settings>Developer options>USB debugging.

Answer (score 0):

click the build number 4 times in the "about phone" menu to unhide the "Developer options"

then "Ensure that USB debugging is enabled under Settings>Developer options>USB debugging."