# Why does vibrate keep turning off on my rooted Galaxy S7?

Tags: vibration, samsung-galaxy-s7

I frequently set my Galaxy S7 to vibrate mode, however it keeps turning vibrate mode back off.  I can't figure out what exactly is causing this.

I know at least one condition that triggers this consistently.  Whenever a call is ended or rejected for any reason, vibrate mode will turn off on its own.  To get around this, when I go to bed I put the phone in airplane mode to prevent any calls from coming in at all, but leave WiFi on so other things still have connectivity.  Unfortunately, I discovered that vibrate is still turning off even when in airplane mode.

This is becoming a major problem as I need to trust that my phone will remain quiet when I need it to.

Comment: Probably an app doing it, especially one that has access to calling. Any app can change your phone's ringer volume with no extra permissions.

Comment: Is there any easy way to find out what app might be doing this?

Comment: It's definitely an app with a running process: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/125388/168531