# How do you see Memory usage in Android O?

Tags: ram, 8.0-oreo

Prior to Android Oreo I could see Memory usage by going to `Settings` > `Memory` but this does not exist any more since upgrading to Android O. Is there any way to see this now or has it been removed completely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Enable Developer Mode ([see here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/33496/30530)), and go to `System` > `Developer options` > `Memory`

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since accepted answer is not applicable in my situation (there is no "Memory" menu item) (Android 8.0.0, Samsung S8), I want to share another way of getting memory usage info. This shows RAM status and RAM usage by applications.

```
Settings > Developer Options > Running Services
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer will only apply when you are a developer, and you have your development PC near.

First make sure that you have **USB debugging** enabled.

Then on your PC open a shell that can run `adb` (of you don't know what this is, then this answer is not for you)

Then in that shell run `adb shell`

This will open a shell to your Android device, within this shell you are running command line applications on your android device.

Now in this adb shell run `top -s rss | head -n 20`. This will print out a list of about 20 apps sorted by RAM usage(-ish, its not precise).

If you are able to enable **ADB Root** in developer options (Again, if you don't know that this is, then it is not for you), then you can see more details:

In the adb shell run `su`. This will elevate your access to the kernel.

Then run `procrank`.
This will show a lot more info about ram and swap usage.

Answer (score -2):

To show memory usage in android Oreo, first of all make sure enable developer mode in android Oreo

**Enable developer mode android Oreo:**

**Settings > System > About phone > Tap build number 7 times**

Now enabled developer options in android 8.0 Oreo.

**Go to settings > System > Developer options > Memory > Memory used by apps**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't add anything new compared to @bmdixon 's answer.