# Trace/log of all activity on my android device

Tags: logging

Is it possible to put on trace or  get log of all activity on android device.
If so, How?Also are there any key logger application

Comment: Are you looking for a keylogger? Or do you want to know where the log files are (which does not track keypresses)?

Comment: @geff_chang I actually need both , something that will help me know what actually happens in background when we perform certain activity on the device and also one key logger app.

Comment: Check this for viewing logs: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log Let's see if somebody else can recommend a keylogger, but you probably will find them if you search for keylogger in Google Play. But I'm pretty sure you won't find an app that will combine both the Android logs, and the keylogger.

Comment: @geff_chang I don't need a single app to do both the tasks.

Comment: Looks like there aren't any keylogger apps in Android. Or at least, I haven't found any in Google Play.

Comment: @geff_chang the link you provided helped a lot for tace/log ,Thanks.For Keylogger, I ll google it :)

Comment: I think [Clip Ninja](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoobees.clipninja&hl=en) would be useful :)

Comment: Keylogger does not exist in android due to the inherent security nature of apps where each app has a unique user-id,and thusly one cannot "intercept" keystrokes from another app... :)