# AFWall+ is not blocking apps

Tags: data-monitoring, firewall, data-plan

I've used [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall&hl=en) to block [Weather Services Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clockweatherpro&hl=en) from using my data plan, but [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en) app still shows it in the top 3 of data plan use.  Is there some background process using data that isn't being blocked?  Is there some other way to block it from using mobile data but still work on Wi-Fi?

HTC Vision/G2 with CM7.2.0 Android 2.3.7

Update: I found [an FAQ](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/wiki/FAQ):

> **How do I know if my phone supports iptables?**
>
> Issue the following command in ADB shell or in Terminal Emulator:
>
> ```
> iptables -L -t nat
> ```

```
$ su
# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Is that correct?

Also this might be the issue, though I don't know how to prove it or troubleshoot it:

> **AFWall+ does not work under CM 7.x, how can i fix this?**
>
> CM 7.x uses old version of iptables which has conflict with AFWall+ built-in iptables. As a workaround you can try to update your iptables to the latest version. But it should work without it. Contact developer/raise an issue on github.

Also, I enabled the "Fix Startup Data Leak" option, and after a reboot, nothing could access the internet at all; it could connect to Wi-Fi but the icon was white indicating no internet connection.  Then I went into AFWall and pressed Apply, and stuff started to work.  Now I can block Browser and when I try to load things in the browser it says "Web page not available" as expected.  So maybe it's working now?

Also firewall log is no longer empty:

```
AppID : 10080
Application Name: Weather Services PRO
Total Packets Blocked: 348
107.23.165.43(40)
74.125.29.95(16)
54.236.89.222(40)
173.194.74.95(4)
54.236.118.224(40)
195.210.29.5(40)
54.236.161.75(40)
157.249.32.164(48)
54.236.175.13(40)
54.236.179.252(40)

---------
AppID : 10167
Application Name: Facebook
Total Packets Blocked: 26
69.171.235.80(6)
173.252.103.16(2)
69.171.242.30(18)

---------
```

So I think that fixed it.  Weather app says "request timed out" and Facebook says "Network Error", but Gmail etc still work.  :D  If it works over the next few days I'll move this into an answer.

Comment: Have you checked if it accessed your data plan recently? If it was a "heavy eater", the top-3 placing could still be because of older, pre-blocking actions. Also, doesn't AFWall+ offer a logging function? Have you checked there for entries whether access was blocked?

Comment: @Izzy: Yeah, it still shows up on daily listings as one of the highest users.  Don't know about logging function, I'll look into it.

Comment: According to its playstore description, *AFWall+* includes a *Rules/Logs Viewer*. From its screenshots, it looks like you should be able to access it via the "menu" ("|") as *Firewall Logs*.

Comment: @Izzy: Yes I see it but it was not enabled so the log is empty.  I'll see what it says in the future.

Comment: Please don't forget to come back then and let us know :)

Comment: @Izzy: Uhhh....  "Log is empty", even after downloading stuff in several apps.  AFWall+ says it's enabled, and has these apps blocked.

Comment: That's strange. As I don't use the app myself, I'm out of ideas -- but I'd say contact the dev and ask for advice (you could send a link to this question along for reference).

Comment: @Izzy: I contacted them first and didn't get a response, but thanks for being helpful about an app you don't even use :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Hopefully we have some AFWall+ users around who might shed some light. I try my best to help, but have some limits sometimes :) One last hint: try utilizing `logcat` (see e.g. [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575) for details) to see what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps post an issue there with AFWall on [Github](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/issues?state=open)? It does not seem to work well with GB 2.3.7 - am trying to incorporate this into my ROM and its failing with weirdness.... just saying...

Comment: Actually....  after each reboot the internet is broken again, and I have to go into AFWall and press *Apply* to get it to work.  That's repeatable enough that I will file a bug.