# How can I get information what happend with my Galaxy S4

Tags: custom-roms, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I bought new Galaxy S4 before two months and from the beginning I have started to experience some serious software issues. Every evening before I go to the bed I connect my phone to charge and in the morning it is frozen (dead, no response) with red light indicator and no response of buttons.

To start the device I have to hold for a long time the power button and only then the device boot.

I have sent it to the service and after two weeks they return it with new software and the problem stopped. Yesterday I made a flash with some xda ROM with serious review and this morning the issue has return.
I know that is my fault and changing the ROM will broke the warranty, but after no one else is experiencing that problem with this ROM I have started to search for an explanation.

The question is how can I record the moment when the phone freeze and view the log after that... Is there some kind of a text file where it holds some information about the processes? The tricky is to view that file after the phone is down and I switched it on...

Thank you!
Sorry for my bad English.. :)

Comment: You should ask this question in XDA Developer forums, not in SO

Comment: Please ask some relevant question, or specify your research on your problem

Comment: I don't think you should have rooted and flashed your phone. If I'm not mistaken, there are full unroot methods available, not sure if that will bring your phone back to the best state it had.

Comment: One solution, charge your phone starting from morning the whole day and keep a watch on when it freezes, rather than finding some app for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with this, I don't think that this question doesn't belong here, because it's related to the Android system logs and that's something we can be helpfull with.

I found a Thread, where the people are discussing various methods to obtain these log information - see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log):

There are several directories where logs (including those from crashes) might appear -- not all of them are standardized (i.e. some may be ROM-specific).

`/data/anr:` Some trace files seem to get here (Dalvik writes stack traces here on ANR, i.e. "Application Not Responding" aka "Force-Close"; see e.g. log excerpts here)

`/data/dontpanic` seems to be a standard location (AOSP), and contains some crash logs including traces (see e.g. viaForensics and StackOverflow)

`/data/kernelpanics` is another location -- not having had any "kernel panic" on my Android devices, I saw no content there yet.

`the /data/panic/panic_daemon.config` may point to other locations configured -- on my Droid 2 it mentions `/sdcard/panic_data/`

`/data/tombstones` may hold several tombstone_nn files (with nn being a serial, increased with every new file). As tombstones are placed for the dead, it is done here for "processes died by accident" (i.e. crashed) -- and it is what is referred to as "core dumps" on Linux/Unix systems. However, not all apps create tombstones; this must be explicitly enabled by the developer (see Debugging Android Core Dumps).

Since you already have root access to your phone, you can even examine the [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#logcat) output through the `adb`.

Here are some other links that might be of use for you:

1. [Link](http://doandroidsdreamofelectricsheep.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/android-system-info/) - The "Android System Info" Application's description
2. [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=crashLog.cutebabyTW) - The "Crash Log (Logcat)" Application (PlayStore link)
3. [Link](http://kobablog.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/how-to-read-crash-dump-of-android/) - *

   - In brief: Since it's a long artice, which describes how to debug, this can be found anywhere in Google (see also "debuggerd"). This is of course if those links ever get down.

**My personal advice - revert to the original Android ROM, which was installed on the Samsung, then perform a revert to factory defaults, go where you bought the phone and ask them to see it once more if the problem persists.**

Cheers

Comment: It would be advisable to include a summary of each of the links above, in event of link rot or 404 error...