# Apps randomly crashing on my ZTE Blade 3. How can I fix this?

Tags: crashes

Applications on my Zte Blade 3 (ICS) crash frequently. They just close without an error message. How can I know if it it's a bug in the app, or a bug in the Android or a flawed device?

**Edit:** Apps that are crashing most frequently are ones which I use the most: Friendly fire game and stock web browser. Per suggestion from comment I've tried clearing data/cache but it did not make a difference.

Comment: What kind of memory does this device have? Is it possible that Android is just killing apps as needed to free memory?

Comment: It has 512 MB RAM. Apps that are crashing are in the foreground which sorta defeats the purpose of releasing the memory?

Comment: A look into the [Android log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log) may reveal the underlying problem. Edit your findings into your question.

Comment: Heavy games may crash due to memory or CPU capacity. The Blade 3 has only 512 MB of RAM, and the CPU has one core, which may cause Android to automatically close heavy apps to free memory. The stock browser crash is a common issue on the Blade 3, I recommend using Google Chrome instead.

Comment: Am interested in this question too. Stock web browser crashes so I installed Maxthon.