# Unfortunately, Music has stopped

Tags: music, htc-one-x, force-close

So recently I've been developing an Mp3 Download app, which may have caused some problems. I've deleted my app, deleted all the content, deleted the 'Music' Apps Cache and Data, yet It still crashes whenever I click on "My Phone" (When selecting music). Or, when I click Folders, Playlist, etc.

---

Device Info:

HTC One X

Android Version: 4.1.1

HTC Sense Version: 4+

Software number: Android Revolution HD 20.1 by mike1986

HTC SDK API Level: 4.63

---

If there's anyone that could help me find a solution, I'd be very happy.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit #1

Just did a cold-boot, and wiped the cache.
This had no effect.   :(

I will not do a Factory Reset, or format my whole phone there's too much that I can't lose. I've read the comments, and the links you've posted.. Unfortunately, none of those links helped me either.

---

Edit #2

Didn't bother trying to fix that, thought it'd just be the flu or something that a week could fix. Didn't care too much tho..

On the other hand, while developing my app, the phone got stuck and didn't do anything. I thought it was a bug in my app. After trying to run the app after some  'Fixes'  the Virtual Android device started to come up (since it didn't detect my phone). I tried to go to settings, to enable USB Debugging (since that's most likely to happen), and it didn't do anything. Phone froze. I shut it down and tried to power it up again. It went to  'HTC quietly brilliant' screen, and froze. I tried to reboot and it got stuck at the same screen.

I tried to power it off, and on one more time, when the Charging LED was no longer on, and the phone went 'Cold' so to speak.

I've tried multiple combinations of buttons, plugged in,not plugged in, with/without Simcard.. but no.

My **HTC One X** is dead. It's still plugged in,on the wall, but it's not charging, booting, nothing.

I am sad.

**Have a nice evening!**

Comment: "Unfortunately, Music has stopped". So sad statement.

Comment: @uprego it really is...

Comment: [You may find the hints about the real cause of the force close in the Android log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log). Feel free to edit any new information in your question.

Comment: And first-aid in our [force-close tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/force-close/info) :)