# Looking for a log file telling me when my phone was on?

Tags: logging

My android 4.4.3 phone was off and in storage but when I got it back the battery was flat and there was some stuff on facebook I can't account for. Is there any log files which would confirm when my phone was on etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer useful. It might help you with what you're looking to accomplish:

[Log file locations](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27892/65486)

As an alternative, there's an app that can help you analyze logs:

[aLogcat (free) - logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)

Comment: I don't think any of that information would help. The crash logs only log crashes, not normal phone use. Both `dmesg` and `logcat` aren't saved to non-volatile storage, so they're only good for telling you what happens while the phone is still on, not previous times it's been on.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking through it and trying some of the apps but wasn't getting anything useful. I'm starting to think there isn't any logs stored on the phone by default.