# Phone automatically reboots

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, reboot

My Lenovo A850 reboots almost every time I answer a call. Using adb I redirected the output to a file. Then I tried tracking the reason for the forced shut-down but I am not sure. The phone has a lot of Lenovo's pre-installed apks. I am posting the stack trace of what **I** **think** might be the error that causes the reboot.

Unfortunatelly I haven't found a decent site to host the stack trace so that you can see the whole thing but I'll give it a try soon.

```
I/AEE/AED (10955): $** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Fatal *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **$
I/AEE/AED (10955): Build Info: 'ALPS.JB5.MP:A850_ROW_S116_130922:MT6582:S01,Lenovo/aupres_row/A850_ROW:4.2.2/JDQ39/A850_ROW_S116_130922.1379859786:user/release-keys'
I/AEE/AED (10955): Flavor Info: 'None'
I/AEE/AED (10955): Exception Log Time:[Wed Oct 29 21:22:51 EET 2014] [99110.120000]
I/AEE/AED (10955): 
I/AEE/AED (10955): Java (JE)
I/AEE/AED (10955): system_server_crash
I/AEE/AED (10955): system_server
I/AEE/AED (10955): Process: system_server
I/AEE/AED (10955): Build: Lenovo/aupres_row/A850_ROW:4.2.2/JDQ39/A850_ROW_S116_130922.1379859786:user/release-keys
I/AEE/AED (10955): 
I/AEE/AED (10955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x28000010 } in android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@42fa4908
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:806)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:1352)
I/AEE/AED (10955): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5351)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1001)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4199)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10529)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  at android.view.View.invalidateParentIfNeede
I/AEE/AED (10955): Backtrace of all threads:
I/AEE/AED (10955): 
I/AEE/AED (10955): "NetdConnector"  prio=5 Thread id=48 RUNNABLE
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:132)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:90)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
I/AEE/AED (10955): 
I/AEE/AED (10955): "Thread-71"  prio=5 Thread id=71 RUNNABLE
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:29)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:92)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  libcore.io.Streams.readFully(Streams.java:81)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:120)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  com.mediatek.agps.MtkAgpsManagerService$MtkAgpsIO.readInt(MtkAgpsManagerService.java:2011)
I/AEE/AED (10955):  com.mediatek.agps.MtkAgpsManagerService$MtkAgpsIO.run(MtkAgpsManagerService.java:1803)
I/AEE/AED (10955): 
I/AEE/AED (10955): "AlarmManager
I/AEE/AED (10955): $** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** Fatal *** *** *** *** *** *** *** **$
```

Comment: As for "a decent site to host the stack trace", [check for the term "pastebin"](https://www.google.com/search?q=pastebin) which several of them carry in their names. Guess for this current post, the formatting did the trick (it's not *too* long). // Looks like the "system server" crashes on you. As that's one of the "lowest layers", it takes the entire system along => Reboot. Not that I could name a cause or even solution...

Comment: Unfortunatelly pastebin.it doesn't allow for such a long file to be uploaded.

Comment: @GeorgeD, pastebin's limit is 512kb. Yours is a mere 3.25kb.

Answer (score 1):

If it's rebooting, you should probably try logging some kernel or other system related messages that are saved after / during a crash, that could show later log messages which probably show what crashed in the lower layers.

Include the log directly before the crash and include it here if it doesn't break formatting, or upload it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) or [nopaste](http://nopaste.info) (larger size limit) if it does.

Try to gather as much information as possible and include these in your question.
Take a quick look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for your question to be more likely to get answers :)
Also tell us: What version of Android or what custom ROM / recovery / etc. are you running exactly?
What did you do before this happened?
What did you already tried?

Here is how you can obtain the different logs:

[How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log)
[Android: How to get kernel logs after kernel panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682306/android-how-to-get-kernel-logs-after-kernel-panic/10525021)
[Shutdown Log in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071547/shutdown-log-in-android)