# Why won't my Android phone access any HTTPS websites through WiFi?

Tags: chrome-for-android, samsung-galaxy-note-3, https

My *Samsung Galaxy Note 3* can not access any secured website while connected via my home WiFi – even applications like Google Search and Facebook can't access the internet and give an error saying "error connecting". Everything works fine when connected via 3G.

Note that my PC and my laptop, using the same router, have no such issues – so it shouldn't be a firewall or the like causing this.

Does anyone have any ideas please on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, which I've integrated with your question (so we can delete above comments now – note you can always [edit] your post ;). This rules out the two reasons I thought of first. A few more details: Could you get some logcat of such an event? If you don't know how to achieve this, please see [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575)

Comment: Thank you for the editing and the comment. I will check and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even I had a similar problem with my One M8, switching to a new ISP helped.