# Unable to send attachment, but there is no email?

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop, nexus-4, attachments

Since I have updated my Nexus4 to Lollipop this error appears in the notification bar : "Unable to send attachment : object". If I tap this error it links me to the sending email and display that there are no e-mail to send.

I searched in my Google mail box but I have no email with this object and I have no elements in the phone with this object.

How can I block this notification?

Comment: "object" is not the name, but the "type" I'd guess. If there's no "outbound mail pending" which could be the cause, have you checked your MMS as well? Even if you're not aware of having composed one, some app might have (or you, just by accident).

Comment: How can I check MMS composition? I have never use MMS function in the past...

Comment: Nor did I, sorry. I'd try with the messaging app. Also worth a try: checking the logs (see: [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575)) They might reveal additional details, e.g. which app is throwing that error. That should help narrowing down.

Comment: If I tap this error it links me to the sending email and display that there are no e-mail to send

Comment: OK, that rules out MMS. Have you checked the logs? Maybe they give some more details.

Comment: The phone is unrooted so I am not able to check the logs

Comment: Oh yes, you can. Have you checked the link I gave you? No root required for that. Again, see [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575) and [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

Comment: The problem seems disappered after a clean update of the smartphone. Maybe the last update was not done in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems disappered after a clean update of Android OS. Maybe the last updateby OTA was not done in the right way and take that error