# Read more about system incidents in Diagnostic application?

Tags: applications, logging, system

Long story short, we bought a new phone: Sony Xperia M4 Aqua dual SIM 16GB version. The phone is on with Android 5.0 and is pretty new, but he doesn't stop keeping restarting itself. (he just blink 2 times the red LED then restart)

I tried to read some debug data with [aLogrec](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogrec) app but without success. At this point, I can clearly see that Android is recording all the incidents data.

Question is: **Is there a way to read more verbose info about this incidents?** The only thing I can see if I tap over that voice is the actual date and time of each incident only :(

PS: even if this phone is made for a dual SIM usage, we are still in need of change the microSIM to a nanoSIM so we are using it without any SIM card.

Refer to below screenshot

[image: diagnostic section under about my phone settings]

Comment: Without superuser access and access to `logcat` and the kernel logs, you are pretty much out of options.

Comment: wow :\ really nice of google, this way you can't try to figure out what's happening without rooting the phone and lose warranty.. also for this phone there's no still rooting options available >_< thanks anyways

Comment: The problem is: Those logs contain sensible information (usernames, tokens, ids etc.) so only system apps or higher (every user id <10000 IIRC) can access those logs. It's not Google, but The Android Foundation (funded mostly by Google) and Linux (the kernel part) who decided that you need to have appropriate permission to access this sensible information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log)