# My android apps sometimes crash

Tags: crashes

Say I am playing clash of clans or boom beach. A crash in the middle of an attack could be very fatal.

What happen is I was playing and then suddenly the screen go back to the home screen. No other apps are running. I can click the multi task button (or whatever button in bottom right) and the original apps shows up. However, it seems to be a crash because if I select it it reloads.

Does android have event logs I can check. What's going on? I got 4 GB memory. It's asus zenphone 2

Comment: [How can I view and examine the Android log?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/27892)

Comment: That one is for the crash. This one is for the log reports location

Comment: They'll lead you to the same thing because ultimately you want to see why the crash occurred? I don't see any difference in the questions but take this as my opinion only. Besides, I did point you to the right source in the comment on your original question. Did you see it?

Comment: Yea. May be I should delete the other question if not too late?

Answer (score 1):

Use `logcat`, the goto Android crash report tool. There are a few ways to use this utility: over adb, in an Android terminal shell, or with an app. If you have root, I suggest using an app like [Logcat Extreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex&hl=en).

Basically just start up the app, go to settings >> Priority Level, and check "Errors." Go back to the main screen, hit the record button. Now repeat everything you explained in your post, opening apps and checking recents. When you're done, go back to Logcat Extreme and hit the record button again. The log will be saved in the folder /sdcard/LogcatX.

The best method, which doesn't require root, is to use logcat in the terminal or over adb. There are a lot of guides for this. [This one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238) can help you logcat on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

When system don't get required resources it generally hangs but due to hanging some apps make memory full, so to avoid data loss system restarts. Same as human brain, if brain is unable to get fresh oxygen it shutdown itself( getting consciousness). You just need to force stop all your apps before playing game. & run game in controlled environment like using some kind of game booster app. I recommend CM SECURITY app, contains inbuilt game booster. It works fine even game is 4 GB & available RAM in your phone is 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

In all Samsung devices with all Android versions OS, try this - Go to phone dial and type `*#9900#` and press button "Run dumpstate/logcat" and then once it is done, press "copy log to SD card".

You would have your entire log activities of your phone from boot until you press this button. Your log would be copied to your SD card.

Comment: I am using asus zenphone