# Does Andriod have an event viewer and how do I access it?

Tags: samsung

I have a new Samsung S7 for 3 months now - My phone crashes in a big way around once a month, I mean I can't even do the factory reset because I cannot get to the recovery screen, no buttons are responsive so holding them to get to the recovery menu is useless, I have to wait till the battery dies before I can recharge it and switch it back on so I can carry out a factory reset before it will crash again (usually 20 minute time frame before it will crash again).

I barley have anything installed (as this is my 3rd time of factory resetting my phone it gets boring re-adding apps etc so only the essential apps are installed whatsapp, bbc news, stock apps)

I work in IT, if this happened on a server I would go view the event viewer to find out what exactly was the root cause, or at least a clue towards why, my question is do android phones have an event viewer hidden away or is there something that I can install that will capture information?

The phone is on the latest firmware & android version and has not been modified or tampered with in any way shape or form.

Kind Regards

Comment: Our [logging tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) might be a good starter :)

Comment: Please check this post it might be helpful: [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/16575)