# Listing all android processes from PC

Tags: adb, linux, usb-debugging, logging

Is there a way to list all the running processes in an Android phone from a PC? Maybe using `adb`?

I remember a mode in the old Eclipse version of Android Studio, was called LogCat. Is it possible to have something similar from console ?

Comment: Naturally `adb shell ps`

Answer (score 2):

Logcat records info, warning and other stuff thrown by apps when necessary - it doesn't explicitly tell you what processes are running.

If the list is what you want, use the classic Linux command `top`. Android also have it (although not as friendly to use). Here's an example output from my own Nexus 6P:

```
shell@angler:/ $ top



User 0%, System 0%, IOW 0%, IRQ 0%
User 15 + Nice 1 + Sys 22 + Idle 2451 + IOW 2 + IRQ 1 + SIRQ 1 = 2493

  PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
 4060  1   0% S    15 1987132K  52032K  fg system   com.quicinc.cne.CNEService
 4913  4   0% R     1   6260K   1432K  fg shell    top
 1423  1   0% S   123 3282976K 134448K  fg system   system_server
 3487  0   0% S    37 2133616K 144432K  fg u0_a19   com.android.systemui
  379  1   0% S    12 197504K  12460K  fg system   /system/bin/surfaceflinger
24196  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/u17:4
10311  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/3:4
 4139  0   0% S    34 2230348K  62884K  bg u0_a156  com.taobao.idlefish:channel
   41  4   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ksoftirqd/4
  258  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     mmcqd/0
    8  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     rcu_preempt
 4848  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/0:2
32569  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/u17:9
  447  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/215-fc38800
  383  1   0% S     1   6356K   1176K  fg root     /system/bin/msm_irqbalance
  297  3   0% D     1      0K      0K  fg root     msm-core:sampli
  245  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     cfinteractive
 4011  0   0% D     1      0K      0K  fg root     mdss_fb0
21510  2   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/2:2
   25  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     perf
   30  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/1:1H
   31  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     smd_channel_clo
   32  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     smsm_cb_wq
   34  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     deferwq
   35  0   0% D     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/u17:0
   36  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     rpm-smd
   38  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/48-cpr
   39  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/51-cpr
   40  4   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     migration/4
   43  4   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/4:0H
   44  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     mpm
   46  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     writeback
   47  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     bioset
   48  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     crypto
   49  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kblockd
   50  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     khubd
   51  4   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     system
   52  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipa_power_mgmt
   53  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     sps_ipa_power_m
   54  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipawq14
   55  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     iparepwq14
   56  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipawq43
   57  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     iparepwq43
   58  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipawq13
   59  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     iparepwq13
   60  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipa_power_mgmt
   61  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipa_rm_wq
   62  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ipa_interrupt_w
   64  4   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kworker/4:1H
   66  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   67  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   68  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   69  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   70  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   71  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   72  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   73  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   74  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   75  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   76  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   77  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   78  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/261-msm_iom
   79  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/263-msm_iom
   80  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/102-msm_iom
   81  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/102-msm_iom
   82  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/102-msm_iom
   83  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/102-msm_iom
   84  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/74-msm_iomm
   85  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/75-msm_iomm
   86  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/75-msm_iomm
   87  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/75-msm_iomm
   88  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/75-msm_iomm
   89  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/273-msm_iom
   90  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/273-msm_iom
   91  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/272-msm_iom
   92  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/97-msm_iomm
   93  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/97-msm_iomm
   94  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/97-msm_iomm
   95  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/350-msm_iom
   96  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/350-msm_iom
   97  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/350-msm_iom
   98  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/298-msm_iom
   99  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/298-msm_iom
  100  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/298-msm_iom
  101  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/79-msm_iomm
  102  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/78-msm_iomm
  103  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/78-msm_iomm
  104  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     devfreq_wq
  105  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     cfg80211
  106  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/15-bcl_vbat
  107  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/460-bcl_iba
  108  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     rpciod
  131  7   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kswapd0
  132  2   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ksmd
  133  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     fsnotify_mark
  134  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     nfsiod
  154  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     ad_calc_wq
  155  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     rot_commit_work
  156  0   0% D     1      0K      0K  fg root     mdss_dsi_event
  157  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     apr_driver
  158  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     pil_vote_wq
  159  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     shm_svc
  160  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     qmi_hndl0000000
  161  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     msm_ipc_router
  162  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     k_hsuart
  163  2   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     msm_serial_hs_0
  164  2   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     msm_serial_hs_0
  165  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     hwrng
  166  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_real_time_
  167  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_modem_data
  168  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_lpass_data
  169  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_wcnss_data
  170  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_sensors_da
  171  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_wq
  172  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     DIAG_USB_diag
  173  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_cntl_wq
  174  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     diag_dci_wq
  175  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kgsl-3d0
  176  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kgsl-events
  177  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     governor_msm_ad
  178  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     kgsl_devfreq_wq
  199  3   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     spi5
  200  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     usbnet
  201  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     sharedmem_qmi_w
  202  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     qmi_hndl0000000
  204  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/212-msm_dwc
  205  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     k_gserial
  206  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     uether
  208  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     dsx_rebuild_wor
  209  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     dsx_exp_workque
  210  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     s2wiwq
  211  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     dt2wiwq
  212  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/502-fpc1020
  215  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     fwu_workqueue
  216  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     msm_cpp_workque
  218  2   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/495-batt-mi
  219  0   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     irq/504-synapti
  220  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     therm_core:noti
  221  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     therm_core:noti
  222  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     therm_core:noti
  223  1   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     therm_core:noti
......
```

It clearly lists *everything* possible (the list scrolls for more than 3 pages).

Comment: `ps` is more fitting option. While `ps` and `top` share most of its source code and features - the obvious difference is that `ps` gives you one time snapshot (what OP wanted) and `top` is designed to provide the same stats continuously (until interrupted by user or specified number of times) optionally sorted by specified column and limited to specified number of processes

Comment: @Пионерка Thanks, I'm not a Linux guy by any means so professional tips are great.

Comment: How do I know which process belongs to which app? On some rare cases, there are multiple processes per app, and there are also processes that have a customized name. Also, seems "ps" doesn't show all processes anymore (shows about 2) even using root. How do I make it show all? Or how do I make "top" to show only current state and that's it?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** [Qdevicemonitor](https://github.com/alopatindev/qdevicemonitor) on your PC

- You can get a logcat using adb command

`adb logcat` and to save it `adb logcat > logcat.txt` and the saved file would be in platform tools directory

To get logcat of different times `adb logcat -v long > logcat.txt`

Source : [Guide on ADB at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2141817)

- In Terminal Emulator:

`logcat > /sdcard/logfile.txt`

- You have several apps on Play Store, [Logcat Extreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=scd.lcex) is one such app ( requires root). More apps can be [found here, thanks to Izzy](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_logcat)
- Related with useful info [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/131553)