# "share via" doesnt pop up any appliction I choose

Tags: share-menu

"share via" had been working for years, it stops to work a few days ago (i didnt update anything the last few days)

I click app "simple Gallery" -> choose a picture -> click "share via" ->  a list of apps I can choose (like viber, whatapps, mail ...) -> choose Viber (or some other) but nothing happens afterwards (no error, nothing. Just the picture)

But If i using the default camera -> display picture (it has its own viewer)  -> "share via" works

What can it be? "simple gallery" had been reinstall, reboot ...nothing help

Comment: Check the [Android log](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14431/2241) for error messages. If there are errors there is a chance to understand what is going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Many thanks for the link, i use "logcat extreme" (catlink requires root, which i dont had). I tried twice, I cant see any permission issue, at the second try, there was "AppCompatDelegate:"?  05-30 17:21:10.266 17939 17956 I [MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f8b470f00), client(32), share_fd(62)  
05-30 17:21:10.332 17939 17956 I [MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0x7f8b473f20), client(32), share_fd(55)
05-30 17:25:52.183 20755 20755 I AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's  
[log]:http://www.chezmoi.dk/share_not_work_log.txt

Comment: sorry coudnt make End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak"  this work :-(

Comment: the developer wrote: I expect you saved a default share setting for some app. This can be confusing to fix. You might try to install the free version and see if it works. If it does, then the default share setting got screwed up.

Comment: i wrote back: yes, default share settings, i did try to reset the default settings for ALL apps. i try reinstall S&R (send and reduced app)  several times with 2 different version, still issue

Comment: I developer ask me to reinstall the free version again....some magic thing happens,  "share" works again as it should.

Comment: sorry, it failed again few hours late. I discover at last "my smartphone policy" (may be me who click somtheing week ago) somehow disable 2 options for "send reduced" at permission -> other permission -> send & reduced. when you enable them and reinstall the app they got disable again. So now everything is ok again. Thanks Robert