# Apps crashing after updating my Samsung S23 Ultra

Tags: samsung

Apps crashing after updating my Samsung S23 Ultra, basically, all games ([Among US](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innersloth.spacemafia&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1), [Sim City](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.game.simcitymobile_row&hl=en&gl=US) etc.) and one [OMGGamer](https://omggamer.com) gaming guide app is getting crashed. Till now almost every time when I open apps they are getting crashed.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Troubleshooting crashing apps is notoriously difficult without any more info. Consider [getting the logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) when the apps crash then [edit] and paste the exception to help determine the cause and possible fixes. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like someone else on [Samsung Community forum](https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-s23-series/apps-crashing/td-p/7051986) is facing a similar issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.