# Why do Google Play Services keep stopping?

Tags: xiaomi, google-play-services, force-stop

I have a Xiaomi Pocophone F1 and I am running MIUI stock 12.0.3 without root but I keep getting Google Play Services keep stopping although I wiped the cache and data of all Google apps and I even did a hard reset.

Here is the bug report:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/beryllium/beryllium:10/QKQ1.190828.002/V12.0.3.0.QEJMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-03-27 03:30:14+0300
pid: 25915, tid: 25953, name: lowpool[2]  >>> com.google.android.gms <<<
uid: 10186
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x7195b40698 (*pc=0xd60003c0)
    x0  000000006f675710  x1  000000006f318580  x2  0000000014621d70  x3  0000000012e0f248
    x4  0000000012e0f390  x5  0000000000000548  x6  0000000012e0f3a0  x7  0000000000000010
    x8  173a4dfd92f63856  x9  173a4dfd92f63856  x10 000000000000006f  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 00000071903b3f38  x15 000000000000a6e3
    x16 0000000000000000  x17 000000000000e6b7  x18 0000007186d02000  x19 00000071e838e800
    x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000000012e0bc90  x22 0000000012e0b8c8  x23 0000000012ec2ce0
    x24 000000006f93b7a0  x25 000000006f2e2918  x26 000000006f318580  x27 0000000012e0bc90
    x28 000000006fdb3398  x29 0000000000000001
    sp  00000071878a04b0  lr  00000071999fafa8  pc  0000007195b40698

backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000005b0d698  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (arxb.a+3720)
      #01 pc 00000000099c7fa4  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (crul.hasNext+228)
      #02 pc 0000000005b02874  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (arwq.hasNext+68)
      #03 pc 0000000005b02874  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (arwq.hasNext+68)
      #04 pc 000000000598cb18  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (aqvy.a+2536)
      #05 pc 0000000005aa44e4  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (arox.run+2724)
      #06 pc 00000000005d7164  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call+68) (BuildId: c67fb07d576b0e0005683e6073a091e35bd99788)
      #07 pc 0000000000829b38  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+200) (BuildId: c67fb07d576b0e0005683e6073a091e35bd99788)
      #08 pc 000000000491cc5c  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (acmu.c+396)
      #09 pc 000000000491d588  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (acmu.run+1304)
      #10 pc 00000000009a90b8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+984) (BuildId: c67fb07d576b0e0005683e6073a091e35bd99788)
      #11 pc 00000000009a55a0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64) (BuildId: c67fb07d576b0e0005683e6073a091e35bd99788)
      #12 pc 000000000496127c  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-Odf-ereYydmTSU7CWg1XXg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (acsa.run+92)
      #13 pc 00000000004afbd8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72) (BuildId: c67fb07d576b0e0005683e6073a091e35bd99788)
      #14 pc 0000000000137334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 03574df7f7eb01baf6baa6348024974c)
      #15 pc 0000000000145fec  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244) (BuildId: 03574df7f7eb01baf6baa6348024974c)
      #16 pc 00000000004b0f10  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104) (BuildId: 03574df7f7eb01baf6baa6348024974c)
      #17 pc 00000000004b2024  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416) (BuildId: 03574df7f7eb01baf6baa6348024974c)
      #18 pc 00000000004f29e0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1176) (BuildId: 03574df7f7eb01baf6baa6348024974c)
      #19 pc 00000000000d7110  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: f6cc5d2d702265511937b56460b37693)
      #20 pc 0000000000075314  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: f6cc5d2d702265511937b56460b37693)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Based on personal experience, bug reports seldom help end-users to troubleshoot the issue. Could you [fetch the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) when it crashes instead?