# Install icon bug on Android 13

Tags: google-play-store

I'm currently facing an issue that seems like Google play is installing something.

There is the same icon that will be shown when installing (on the right side of Adobe) an application but when I open Google play it does not show that something is getting installed.

Is this a known issue on Android 13?
How can I fix it?

When I press the icon Google play starts and an load error will be shown.

[image]

Made a factory reset as this bug was draining and heating up my battery very fast.
I am on a Sony Xperia 5 III (without any launcher)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. I've personally never seen such an animation when installing an app from Play Store. What happens if you long-press it? Also, could you [edit] and mention the device model and the launcher app, just in case it's relevant? Have you tried other launchers and observed the same behavior? Otherwise, if you have access to ADB, you might want to try [checking the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) and see the `Intent` when it's clicked. There might be an extra data mentioning the package name of the app.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for your response, it was on a Sony Xperia 5 III with the default launcher. Long press didn't make any difference it just showed the information icon, but was not able to delete the application.  I made a factory reset as it was causing some more issues. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you install any unknown apk? Very often, this kind of "hidden" apps are downloaded from malicious AD websites who pretend to give the file you need. Not sure if this is one of them.