# Doorbell AnyHome app does not work on Android SDK Emulator

Tags: applications, android-emulator, android-sdk

I am not used to Android Studio/SDK but try to use it for the first time to emulate an app (Doorbell AnyHome) on my laptop.

I succeeded to:

- create an AVD (Pixel 4 API 32 -a12L)
- download the app from the Play Store
- run the app and try to connect to the doorbell with sonic configuration. But, even if I heard "pairing received", the app keeps sending the sound trying to connect.

I only see these warning messages in the terminal and don't know if they are linked to my problem.

```
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 32 -a12L - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 32 -a12L - cannot add library .../Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed
WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 32 -a12L - *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
```

And my question is, any way to get more debug/trace messages to see the app running/blocking?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like the warning you got is a warning about the emulator itself, which doesn't seem to be related to the problem with the app. However, production apps tend to suppress debugging log messages, so depending on what issues and logs you want to check, it may be hard/impossible to achieve that. Meanwhile, we have a canonical question for [viewing various logs on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325).

Comment: Thank for your answer, I'll review your link about logs.