# How can I tell what has happened on my phone? Like a log

Tags: security, logging

I'm looking to find out if there is a way to log activities on my phone, like something that tells you something was uploaded, downloaded, installed, SMS sent, number called, etc., anytime the phone is on. I keep falling asleep at odd times, and when I wake up, my phone is in a different space, like I have my screen turned to never shut off but it will be off. I'm always doing something on my phone when I fall asleep, but it's never near me and I.

Being told that I put it somewhere, I never feel tired when I fall asleep, I guess I just pass out somehow. Anyway, when I wake up 4 to 6 hours later, I have been checking my digital well-being to find out what was opened hourly on my phone, and there are apps that have been opened several times during the time when I was sleeping. I need to know what happens in these apps i.e., did they read messages, download or screenshot something, send a file, make a call, send a text? They are doing something and may even have installed something on my phone, but I doubt that if they believe they have consistent access to it.

I hoped to catch what they were doing by using a screen recorder all day so it would catch anything that happens in case I passed out again, as it's almost a nightly occurrence by now. But when I woke up, this time everything was deleted, even from the first screen recording to the last four of the day. And yes, I'm certain the screen recorder was running because I waited to start it until a webinar came on I needed to watch.

Something is going on with me I'm sure what, but I don't have anyone in my corner and don't want to sound paranoid because I'm pretty rational, but if it doesn't make sense then it doesn't make sense. I need help quickly. Anything that can help protect me? I use pattern lock and factory ROM. Nothing unoriginal on a Moto 5G Stylus which is up to date, but I am more interested in counter-surveillance strategies. I feel like it's very important to know what they are doing while I "pass out".

Maybe there is something like a keylogger or something but for files and pictures. The reason for my concern is I deal with people's private information on a daily basis and I have in the past used this phone to transfer or edit a file, sending it back to my secure tablet before I was aware of this issue, but I don't know how long this has been going on. I've been passing out like this sporadically for a few weeks at a time for the past couple of years. Thanks for your help, anything is appreciated very much.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have at least a canonical Q&A about logging on [How can I view and examine the Android log?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325). Hopefully, you might find that helpful while waiting for further suggestions.