# Android TV removing app

Tags: applications, side-loading, play-protect

I downloaded and installed a 3rd party app which was not on the app store

The problem I have is that every time I turn on my TV, it gets removed and I am forced to reinstall the app

I have found that after reinstalling, on occasions, when I am using the app, if the app gets closed and removed.

I have turned off play protect and it still happens

What is the best way to stop this from happening?

**
I have sldo tried using a different installer (apk mirror installer) same outcome

Comment: Have you tried other apps? May be the TV has a function to uninstall all "unauthorized" apps? What TV brand and model do you own?

Comment: The best way to stop this from happening is to know the cause first. If possible, [get the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) when it happens. Otherwise, it will mostly be a guesswork.